# proof of a tree with two vertices of degree three

Tags: graph-theory

This is a practice question from the text.

The Question : Show that a tree with two vertices of degree $3$ must have at least four vertices of degree $1$. I have the answer to PART A.

Part B) Show that the result of Part (a) is the best possible i.e. a tree with two vertices of degree $3$ need not have five vertices of degree $1$.

I would really appreciate a hint that could help me solve part B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Part B, consider this tree: >-<

Comment: thanks for the reply. So should my proof be that the tree >-< is the simplest form of a tree with two vertices of degree 3 and it clearly has 4 vertices of deg 1.

Comment: You only need one example to show (a) is best possible, and this does the trick.  Others will too, e.g. >----<

Comment: thankyou again, that is very intuitive however is there a way to prove that the result in Part a is the best possible. As just sketching the graph >-< only shows that result of Part a is possible but not the best possible. I could be over thinking this.

Comment: I think your difficulty stems from understanding what it means that "the result in Part a is the best possible". You have proved a lower bound on something (namely, the number of vertices of degree 1 in a tree with two vertices of degree 3 _is at least_ 4). If this were _not_ the best possible, that means that there would be a better lower bound, i.e. a higher lower bound. A higher lower bound would be at least 5. But 5 can not be a lower bound: >-< is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you you were right I was having a hard time understanding the  fact that it is best possible and your explanation helped. Thanks vadmin123 and Mees de Vries

Comment: I am not getting how it is "at least"? All my efforts to form binary tree with 2 nodes with degree 3 yields "exactly" four nodes with degree 1: 3 leaves and 1 root. My tree is essentially same as(>-<). Even if I add one more edge say: ( >-<_ ), then still there are 4 nodes with degree 1. How can there be more than four degree 1 nodes in such a binary tree. Can you please give example?

Comment: @PardonMeForMySuperPoorMaths, "a tree with two vertices of degree 3"  allows a tree with seven vertices of degree 3, or a tree with two vertices of degree 3 and another  vertex of degree 5.

Comment: ohh do you mean that it says "at least" two vertices of degree 3 implying tree can have anything else as long as "it has at least two vertices of degree 3"?

Comment: I have an arm.  I also have a second arm, and two legs.

Comment: lolz I assume you mean yes to my question in earlier comment presuming you will correct me if am wrong (with riddle-less approach)